# Trying to find out the title of a sci-fi book where characters filter sensations through animals

Tags: books, story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title/author of a book.
I'll try to provide as many details as I can.

I remember this character who had some kind of digital socket in his brain.
He could not only record/load experiences from his memory, but he could also process them with some kind of filtering.
For instance, I remember that he processed a memory as if it was lived by a dog to enhance smell and hearing.
One more thing, I remember clearly that these experiences were called "picchi" in italian (which was the language in which I read the book). I think the closest translation is "peaks" or "spikes" in english.
If you don't remember the title but you can give me more details I would appreciate that too!

Thanks to everyone in advance for their answers.

EDIT:
I read this book in italian, maybe three or four years ago, but I'm 99% sure that the book was translated from english.
It might be Palahniuk or Philip K. Dick, if this helps.

SOLVED:
It is "Rant" by Chuck Palahniuk. Italian title was "Rabbia".

Comment: Nice job on finding the answer! Maybe having to provide more details helped you to remember things you thought you'd forgotten? :-) Why not go ahead and post this as an actual answer (there should be an "answer your question" button in the bottom left), and then after 48 hours (I think) you can accept it, by clicking the checkmark on the left, so that this question is marked as solved.

Comment: Ahahah, you got it right! I thought about which authors could have written the book to help finding the answer, so I started googling words+author until I found it. I will certainly transform this in a solved question!

Answer (score 4):

It is "Rant" by Chuck Palahniuk. Italian title was "Rabbia".

ps. It's a weird but great book